# How to calculate y value for given x using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have defined a line generator with `d3.js` as follows:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("monotone")
    .x(function(d) {return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) {return y0(d.visits); });
```

The data is read from a csv with the following format:

```
date,visits
12/08/12,1
13/08/12,0
14/08/12,0
15/08/12,33
16/08/12,28
```

The csv file is loaded into `data`, and parsed as:

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = d3.time.format("%d/%m/%y").parse(d.date);
    d.visits = +d.visits;
});
```

and added to the document with:

```
svg.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line)
```

Elsewhere in my script, I need to work out what the y value is at a particular date. So for example, I might want to get a y value for the line where the date is `15/08/12` (equivalent to `y0(33)`). How can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`bisect`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_bisect) to find the date in your array and then call the `y0` function. The code would look something like this (taken pretty much straight from the documentation):

```
var bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.date; }).right;
...   
var item = data[bisect(data, new Date(2012, 8, 15))];
y0(item.visits);
```

Note that this approach requires your dates to be sorted, which they are in your example data.

Comment: Thanks, this works, although actually I had to use `item = data[bisect(data), new Date (2012, 8, 15))-1];`. Since the match is exact I need the element to the left of the element to the right, hence the -1. A bit of a hack, but it works. In my case there is data for all dates -- if this is not the case, then this approach might not work.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**

To piggy back off of Lars' example, with a minor tweak to avoid -1 hacks:

```
var bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.date; }).left;
...   
var item = data[bisect(data, new Date(2012, 8, 15))];
y0(item.visits);
```

**Original Post**

rudivonstaden, you can use the .left function attached to the bisector instead of the .right in Lars' example -- that way you do not have to do the -1 hack that you did.