# How to calculate y value for given x using d3 line generator?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've check out [the another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16238713/how-to-calculate-y-value-for-given-x-using-d3-js) but seems that it works for the specific value in the **array**.

However, I use a line generator to draw a curve and I need to get the calculated *y* value for any given *x* value. I think there may be some functions related to line generator but I've not found one.

And my code is like:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) {
        return xLinear(d.ts); // time
    })
    .y(function(d) {
        return yLinear(d.value); // value
    })
    .interpolate('monotone');
```

So my question is how to calculate *y* value for any given *x* (time)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Share the same question