# Given an x coordinate, how can you find y coordinate in d3.js

Tags: d3.js, react-native

I've created a line graph over time using d3 and Art in React native.

I would like a small circle which sits on the line in the center of the screen and follows the line up and down as the user swipes horizontally back and forward.

The line:

```
scaleX = d3.scale.scaleTime()
    .domain([start, end])
    .range([0, width]);

scaleY = d3.scale.scaleLinear()
      .domain([minY, maxY]).nice()
      .range([height, 0]);

lineShape = d3.shape.line()
      .x((d) => scaleX(d.date))
      .y((d) => scaleY(d.value))
      .curve(d3.shape.curveCardinal.tension(0.5));
```

The graph:

```
<ScrollView horizontal={true} onScroll={this.scrollMoved}>
  <Surface width={800} height={200}>
    <Group x={0} y={0}>
      <Shape d={lineShape(data)} stroke="#333"/>
    </Group>
  </Surface>
</ScrollView>
```

My current train of thought is to get the X and Y coordinates of the line at the center of the screen and then update the circles Y position while scrolling.
Using the ScrollView I can get the current X position but I can't see how using d3 I can get the Y position based on this.

There maybe a better way to do this, so any other methods are welcomed suggestions.

Comment: Do you want to take Y point while you are scrolling ?

Comment: Yes I would like to calculate Y for the line continuously while scrolling

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate y value for given x using d3.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16238713/how-to-calculate-y-value-for-given-x-using-d3-js)